# DataGridView does not display all the value with empty images from the database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio, datagridview

`DataGridView` does not display all the value with empty images from the database.

There is a problem with displaying data from the database. I use MySql. And I have field with the image which can have a null value.

But when I try to display all the records in the `DataGridView` from MySql it only displays those records in which there are images.
But when doing the search there are strings when can appear without images.
What is the problem?
Maybe the problem is in here:

```
public void GetViewImageInCellTable(DataGridView dataGridView, int numberColumn)
{
   DataGridViewImageColumn imgCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
   imgCol = (DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridView.Columns[numberColumn];
   imgCol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of your gridview and provide some more information?

Comment: I'll add the complete code that is involved in the mapping data.

Comment: Just boot datagridView not displayed fields with empty values, only with pictures.

Comment: but when looking for value then displays empty values. Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void FillDataGridView(DataGridView dataGridView,  int height, int[] cellsImages, string query = "")
    {
        try
        {
            command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection); //Создаём запрос для поиска
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command); //Выполняем команду
                                                     //Для отображения в таблице
            DataTable table = new DataTable(); //Создаём таблицу
            adapter.Fill(table); //Вставляем данные при выполнении команды в таблицу

            Settings settings = new Settings();
            //настраиваем отображение таблицы
            settings.GetSettingDisplayTable(dataGridView, height);
            dataGridView.DataSource = table; //подключаем заполненную таблицу и отображаем
            //Для отображения картинки в DataGridView
            settings.GetViewImageInCellTable(dataGridView, cellsImages);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void GetSettingDisplayTable(DataGridView dataGridView, int height)
    {
        dataGridView.RowTemplate.Height = height; //высота строк
        dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false; //нельзя пользователю добавлять самому строки
        //Как будет отображаться таблица
        dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        //Растягивать таблицу (колонки) под окно dataGridView
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just boot datagridView not displayed fields with empty values, only with pictures.
[With images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2aNM.jpg)
but when looking for value then displays empty values. Why?
[Without images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvioy.jpg)